# Transitive type inferrence in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Take the following code snippet as an example:

```js
function foo(t: "number"): number
function foo(t: "string"): string
function foo(t: "boolean"): boolean
function foo(t: "number" | "string" | "boolean"): number | string | boolean {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        if (t === "number") {
            return 1;
        } else if (t === "boolean") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return "1";
        }
    } else {
        return foo(t);
    }
}
```

The detailed error is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(t: "number"): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "boolean"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"number"'.
      Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"number"'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(t: "string"): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "boolean"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"string"'.
      Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"string"'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(t: "boolean"): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "boolean"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"boolean"'.
      Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"boolean"'.(2769)
```

However, the following code passes typescript check:

```js
function bar(t: "number"): number
function bar(t: "string"): string
function bar(t: "boolean"): boolean
function bar(t: "number" | "string" | "boolean"): number | string | boolean {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        if (t === "number") {
            return 1;
        } else if (t === "boolean") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return "1";
        }
    } else {
        switch (t) {
            case "number": return bar(t);
            case "string": return bar(t);
            case "boolean": return bar(t);
        }
    }
}
```

See [typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/aNnoBm).

My question is why typescript denies transitive type inference in the first code snnipet.
Could anyone help me with that and thanks a lot.

Comment: That's because ```t``` in the ```else``` branch is of type ```number | string | boolean``` and there is no signature of ```foo``` with an argument of this type.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев Sorry, there are some errors in code and I've fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to "how", but here's what:

```
function bar<T extends "number" | "string" | "boolean">(t: T): T {
```

If you needs something more elaborate, there's a painfully inconvinient

```
function bar<T extends "number" | "string" | "boolean">(t: T): T extends "number" ? number : T extends "string" ? string : boolean
```

Comment: Yes, this can be a good alternative to what the author is using!

Comment: I got your point but unfortunately it still fails. [here](https://tsplay.dev/9WvoQw)

Comment: @TTY112358 yeah that's why "painfully inconvinient" https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEAiMEAWwCNsAncxAHwpKgZjAHNm3ytVABtsAQzDkAfAAooALkQYAlIqx4CxMpRr0miAPyIqdRojU58hUu07c+hxBy69ziIXFETEAbwBQiIGIDNhQIAxIKHByyohiZOpWWhQmesxGqWY1WGtbazvbpTnauih5eYADcfgC+QA

Comment: Yeah, "as" definitely can solve this problem. It can be a working solution while I'm still wondering if there is more elegant one. Thanks anyway!